# Unexpected error from a table that was working correctly

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm simply doing a select * from one of my tables. It is a daily table containing yesterday's data and was working fine yesterday and earlier today. It is suddenly returning "Error: Unexpected. Please try again."

Are there any production issues currently? The job id for one of these failed queries is job_Tj_vZhAqfZH9jpW52M8IUld4XKE

Comment: I confirm this fails for us too, BQ seams to be down right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A configuration change this morning caused a problem querying from tables that had been written to via streaming. The issue should be fixed now. Please ping this thread if you continue to see problems.

Comment: No more issues for me. Is there a status page / mailing list or something similar that we can use to check for production issues with BigQuery? It would be quite helpful when we encounter problems to know if it isn't something on our side.